# How to extract a substring from inside a string?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string `/Apath1/Bpath2/Cpath3/0-1-2-3-4-5-something.otherthing` I want to extract just the '0-1-2-3-4-5' part. I tried this:

```
str='/Apath1/Bpath2/Cpath3/0-1-2-3-4-5-something.otherhing'

print str[str.find("-")-1:str.find("-")]
```

But, the result is only 0. How to extract just the '0-1-2-3-4-5' part?

Comment: How do you want to determine what to extract?  You say you want to extract "0-1-2-3-4-5", but how are you deciding by looking at it that that's what you want to extract?  What if there's another hyphen somewhere else in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
str='/Apath1/Bpath2/Cpath3/0-1-2-3-4-5-something.otherhing'
print str[str.find("-")-1:str.rfind("-")]
```

`rfind` will search from the end. This assumes that no dashes appear anywhere else in the path. If it can, do this instead:

```
str='/Apath1/Bpath2/Cpath3/0-1-2-3-4-5-something.otherhing'
str = os.path.basename(str)
print str[str.find("-")-1:str.rfind("-")]
```

`basename` will grab the filename, excluding the rest of the path. That's probably what you want.

**Edit:**

As pointed out by @bradley.ayers, this breaks down in the case where the filename isn't exactly described in the question. Since we're using `basename`, we can omit the beginning index:

```
print str[:str.rfind("-")]
```

This would parse '/Apath1/Bpath2/Cpath3/10-1-2-3-4-5-something.otherhing' as '10-1-2-3-4-5'.

Comment: What if it was `'/Apath1/Bpath2/Cpath3/10-1-2-3-4-5-something.otherhing'`?

Comment: @bradley.ayers - Then he'd get `10-1-2-3-4-5`, just as expected.

Comment: @bradley.ayers - Good catch. I made the minimal change necessary to the OP's example and forgot to make the code robust. Updated with a fix.

Answer (score 5):

Use os.path.basename and rsplit:

```
>>> from os.path import basename
>>> name = '/Apath1/Bpath2/Cpath3/0-1-2-3-4-5-something.otherhing'
>>> number, tail = basename(name).rsplit('-', 1)
>>> number
'0-1-2-3-4-5'
```

Comment: +1 I think I like this better than mine. `rsplit` is cleaner than slicing IMO.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
>>> str='/Apath1/Bpath2/Cpath3/0-1-2-3-4-5-something.otherhing'
>>> str.split('/')[-1].rsplit('-', 1)[0]
'0-1-2-3-4-5'
```

Assuming that what you want is just what's between the last '/' and the last '-'. The other suggestions with `os.path` might make better sense (as long as there is no OS confusion over what a a proper path looks like)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> ss = '/Apath1/Bpath2/Cpath3/0-1-2-3-4-5-something.otherhing'
>>> re.search(r'(?:\d-)+\d',ss).group(0)
'0-1-2-3-4-5'
```

While slightly more complicated, it seems like a solution similar to this might be slightly more robust...